# jQuery Mobile iPhone-like Image Gallery

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I've done a bit of searching but I can't find what I'm looking for. I'm using the photoswipe plugin for jquery mobile to scroll my images but I need to have them displayed nicely on my page to begin with. I'd like an iphone-like photo grid like what happens when I click on photos on my iPhone, and then those photos to link into the PhotoSwipe. Also, it needa to be formatted as a  for PhotoSwipe.

Is that purely css? If so, could someone help me out with the styling? I'm terrible with css I don't have the mind for design like that. (I understand it, I'm just not good at it).

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this example do what you want: http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/04-jquery-mobile.html ?

Comment: @Melissa ya that's what I want but I need the CSS to make it do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

CSS --

```
#container img {
    float  : left;
    width  : 30%;
    height : auto;
}
```

This will put three images on each line, and they will always just-about fill the screen (there should be 10% of the width left-over for spacing).

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sy764/

## Update

I made the container a `UL` element and wrapped each image in a `LI` element. Here is the CSS to make the images display as approximately one third of the page's width:

```
#container li {
    float   : left;
    width   : 30%;
    height  : auto;
    padding : 3px;
}

#container li img {
    width  : 100%;
    height : auto;
}​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sy764/1/

Comment: @JoshDG Yes it should still work if the images are inside list-items. However you can just set the CSS I provided on the list-items and then set the width of each of the images to 100%. See my **update** for an example.

Comment: Oo that's perfect! Altho theres a lot of whitespace on the left how do I get rid of that?

Comment: @JoshDG Just add some padding to the `li` elements and they will be spaced.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the example at http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/04-jquery-mobile.html, set this on your list elements:

```
.gallery li {
float: left;
width: 33.33333333%;
}
```

This sets the width if the `li` and all its contents.

Comment: Ya thats awesome! Except the pictures seem kinda set off to the right ..theres some white space on the right... and ideally there would be some space between the pictures....so that they're each like their own square...sorry I don't mean to make you do my work for me I'm just baaad with making CSS look pretty

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of late for this answer, but this is the exact css values that PhotoSwipe uses in the jQueryMobile example:

```
.gallery { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
.gallery:after { clear: both; content: "."; display: block; height: 0; visibility: hidden; }
.gallery li { float: left; width: 33.33333333%; }
.gallery li a { display: block; margin: 5px; border: 1px solid #3c3c3c; }
.gallery li img { display: block; width: 100%; height: auto; }
#Gallery1 .ui-content, #Gallery2 .ui-content { overflow: hidden; }
```